# PHP: properly truncating strings with ".."

Tags: php

Currently, the method I use to truncate strings is: `echo substr($message, 0, 30)."..";`

How do I show the dots only in the case that the string has been truncated?

Comment: Why two dots in place of the usual three? Not every deviation from the norm is good. If you care about the “lost” character, you can have the hyperbolic ellipse (that’s what the three dots are called) in *one* character, thanks to Unicode: `…` (try to select it with the mouse, you’ll see that it’s indeed only one character).

Comment: Also, a hyperbolic ellipsis is NOT three dots, or periods. The ellipsis is an entirely separate entity, and should not be willy-nilly replaced with three dots, as they both have different properties as characters, and also take up different spacing in text. Use the actual ellipsis-character instead.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just check the length to see if it's more than 30 characters or not:

```
if (strlen($message) > 30)
{
    echo substr($message, 0, 30)."..";
}
else
{
    echo $message;
}
```

The typographic nitpick in me has this to add: the correct character to use is the ellipsis which comprises this character `…`, *three* dots `...`, or its HTML entity `&#133;`.

Comment: Ha! You were 18 seconds quicker :)

Comment: (Especially @fabrik and whoever who voted him up:) Using named entities in HTML is deprecated – don’t do it, since (modern!) browsers will choke on it when used together with XHTML. A better solution is always to use the character directly, along with a correct encoding, i.e. UTF-8 or similar. But +1 for mentioning the correct symbol nonetheless.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: thanks! Seems I haven't been in the loop about the deprecation. Fixed my answer!

Comment: I think that you should use `mb_substr()` to be UTF-8 safe :)

Answer (score 6):

Just check the length of the original string to see if it needs to be truncated. If it is longer than 30, truncate the string and add the dots on the end:

```
if (strlen($message) > 30) {
 echo substr($message, 0, 30)."..";
} else {
 echo $message;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if (strlen($message) > 30) {
  echo substr($message, 0, 30) . "..";
} else {
  echo $message;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It should be noted that the strlen() function does not count characters, it counts bytes.  If you are using UTF-8 encoding you may end up with 1 character that is counted as up to 4 bytes.  The proper way to do this would be something like:

```
echo mb_strlen($message) > 30 ? mb_substr($message, 0, 30) . "..." : $message;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
echo strlen($message) > 30 ? substr($message, 0, 30) . '..' : $mssage;
```

Basically, it's like (but shorter):

```
if (strlen($message) > 30) {
    echo substr($message, 0, 30) . "..";
} else {
    echo $message;
}
```

Comment: shorter but it's barbarian language, unlike plain and simple English `if str[ing] len[gth] [of the] message more than 30...`

Comment: True, but I like the ternary syntax for this kind of thing.  It's shorter and more to the point.  It also is the textbook scenario for its usage (branching logic with the same "outcome" with both branches)...

Answer (score 1):

Add a `strlen()` condition?