# Not returning desired substring when strpos is used for making sure that it ends with a word only

Tags: php

I am using the following function for extracting substring from a description field and also make sure that it ends with a complete word only.

```
function smalldescription($msg)
{
    $message=substr($msg, 0, strpos($msg, ' ', 500));
    $message=$message."...";
    return $message;
}
```

My problem is, if the $msg is a lenghty description, then the function is returning 500 characters finely. But if $msg is not a lengthy description, say only 20 characters, then the resultant string is as `...` only. Can anyone help me to solve the problem.

Comment: Dublicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502889/php-substr

Comment: Your strpos() returns FALSE if $msg doesn't contain any ' '. So substr() returns empty line too in this situation. Is it your case?

Comment: What do you want to get? Your function will cut input string till first space, so it's original length means nothing, only space position defines result string length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this

```
function smalldescription($msg)
{

if (strlen($msg) > 500)
{
    $message=substr($msg, 0, strpos($msg, ' ', 500));
    $message=$message."...";
    return $message;
}
else
{
     return $msg;
}

}
```